# High-precedence application expressions as arguments

Tags: f#

A high precedence application expression is one in which an identifier is immediately following by a left paren without intervening whitespace, e.g., `f(g)`. Parentheses are required when passing these as function arguments: `func (f(g))`.

[Section 15.2 of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#HighPrecedenceApplication) states the grammar and precedence rules allow the unparenthesized form -- `func f(g)` -- but an additional check prevents this.

Why is this intentionally prohibited? It would obviate the need for excessive parentheses and piping, and generally make the code much cleaner.

A common example is

```
raise <| IndexOutOfRangeException()
```

or

```
raise (IndexOutOfRangeException())
```

could become simply

```
raise IndexOutOfRangeException()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the need for writing the additional parentheses is a bit annoying. I think that the main reason why it is not allowed to omit them is that adding a whitespace would then change the meaning of your code in quite a significant way:

```
// Call 'foo' with the result of 'bar()' as an argument
foo bar()

// Call 'foo' with 'bar' as the first argument and '()' as the second 
foo bar ()
```

There are still some rough edges where adding parens changes the evaluation (see this [form post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/fsharpgeneral/thread/0b6f7ad3-a861-4145-b508-13ac534a6982/)), but that "just" changes the evaluation order. This would change the meaning of your code!

Comment: That doesn't seem like a problem in a language where whitespace is so significant. :-)

Comment: @Daniel - I guess it is a matter of choice, to what extent should the whitespace be significant. Taking it further, we could also write `goo   foo 1   bar 2` for `goo (foo 1) (bar 2)` using two-space notation :-). (EDIT: which would make posting to SO comments difficult, because the double-space is ignorred here...)

Comment: Not to be overly pedantic, but `some` or `no` whitespace seems like a more significant distinction than `1` or `N`.

Comment: @Daniel I agree that it may be a completely reasonable option. The two-space idea was really just a joke. Relying on the space would probably confuse mainly existing functional programmers using OCaml or Haskell, but it would fit with some things in F#. I'm not entirely convinced, but it looks like an interesting option.

Comment: @Daniel we should fork our own version of F# and make `raise IndexOutOfRangeException()` legal.